# confusion in acquiring and releasing of locks

Tags: java, android, locks

I have the following code snippet from Client of an Android emulator:

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,String sortOrder) {
    String key = selection;     
    String keyHash = genHash(key);
    Log.v("provider.query","Key & keyHash: "+key+" & "+keyHash);
    if(SimpleDhtUtil.toForward(keyHash, currentHash, predecessorHash)){
        DhtDto dto = new QueryTransfer(successorPort, currentPort, -1, key, keyHash);
        st.makeSendRequest(dto);
        synchronized(BigLock.LOCK){
            SimpleDhtUtil.cursorReset();
            requiredAnswers = 1;
            currentAnswers = 0;
        }   
        while(requiredAnswers>currentAnswers){
            synchronized(BigLock.LOCK){

                try{
                    if(requiredAnswers>currentAnswers){
                        Log.d("provider.externalQueryLock","CA: "+currentAnswers+"RA: "+requiredAnswers+" Waiting... "+BigLock.LOCK);
                        BigLock.LOCK.wait();
                        Log.d("provider.externalQueryLock","Woke up");
                    }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                Log.e("provider.query", "InterruptedException",e);
            }
        }
    }
    return SimpleDhtUtil.getCursor();
}
```

The following code in the Server of the same AVD:

```
private void acceptAnswer(QueryAcknowledge qa) {                
//  Object lock = SimpleDhtProvider.externalQueryLock;
    synchronized(BigLock.LOCK){
        SimpleDhtProvider.currentAnswers += 1;
        Log.d("ReceiverTask.acceptAnswer","Got result. Current count: "+SimpleDhtProvider.currentAnswers);
        SimpleDhtUtil.addValues(qa.getRecords());
        Log.d("ReceiverTask.acceptAnswer","Aggregated result. Net count: "+SimpleDhtUtil.getCursor().getCount());       
        BigLock.LOCK.notifyAll();
        Log.d("ReceiverTask.acceptAnswer","lock released: "+BigLock.LOCK);
    }       
}
```

Now the problem is that when releasing the lock in the server code, I want the lock in the client to be notified and awoken. This happens >80% of the time. But sometimes it gets stuck. Find the android log below. Also, the currentAnswers and requiredAnswers are always being handled from the client, i.e., these variables are static and volatile in Client and BigLock is an enum with only one value as LOCK.

Client log:

```
04-14 08:14:07.172: V/provider.query(2699): Key & keyHash: 6oLNUimWIuAM4YWN183cwtz0te5aq6r7 & 837cccd1cac03a9c4c9169fad595a997d2673920
04-14 08:14:07.202: D/provider.externalQueryLock(2699): CA: 0RA: 1 Waiting... LOCK
```

Server log:

```
04-14 08:14:07.192: D/ReceiverTask.acceptAnswer(2699): Got result. Current count: 2
04-14 08:14:07.192: D/ReceiverTask.acceptAnswer(2699): Aggregated result. Net count: 2
04-14 08:14:07.192: D/ReceiverTask.acceptAnswer(2699): lock released: LOCK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that I was resetting the cursor after sending the request from the client assuming that the Server would receive reply after resetting the cursor in the next line.

The correct order is first reset the cursor and then send the request.